# Trouble running existing react-native project on Android emulator

Tags: android, macos, android-emulator, react-native

I’m currently trying to set up an existing react-native project on an android emulator (OSX).

I’m having some trouble with this error particularly:

```
Execution failed for task :react-native-lock:processReleaseResources
```

After running `$(npm bin)/react-native run-android`.

Any wisdom would be super appreciated!

Comment: For more context, the rest of the error message says:
  `BUILD FAILED`
  `Total time: 14.346 secs`

It suggests I add --stacktrace, --info, or --debug to the command, but when i try i get an `error: unknown option`.
and when i do `adb devices` it shows that im attached to the emulator that i have running.

Answer (score 0):

Try using

2. cd android
3. ./gradlew clean
4. cd..
5. react-native run-android

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion. I tried this and still get the same error.